# How to stop a line of code from running, if a input is empty

Tags: php, file-upload, input

I have this line of code, and i would like it to not run when "beg_img" is empty, i got the code from w3schools and changed minior things, im pretty new to this, but i guess i have to use some kind og if/else isset?

```
<?php
$target_dir = "../../img/images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["beg_img"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["beg_img"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["beg_img"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg") {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG & PNG files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["beg_img"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["beg_img"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}

$beg_i_img = basename($_FILES["beg_img"]["name"]);

?>
```

Comment: Wrap your code in `if( isset($_FILES["beg_img"]) ) { //your code } `

Comment: You can check :

if ($_FILES["beg_img"]["name"] != '' )
{
  // Code here

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can try this at the beggining of your script:

```
// If no file was uploaded
if($_FILES['beg_img']['error'] == 4){
    return;
}
```

And it's better to validate some things like the one you want at the beggining of your script than wrap all your code with an `if`, because one more wrap, then another and another...if we can avoid it, the code will be better :)

You should check `return` and maybe `continue`, will help you in your scritps :)

Answer (score 0):

Surround your entire code with an "if":

```
if (($_FILES["beg_img"]) != NULL) && (!empty($_FILES["beg_img"])) { 
   //yourcode 
}
```

You can also check directly if the $_FILES["beg_img"] not exists with

```
if (isset($_FILES["beg_img"])){
   //yourcode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if (isset($_FILES["beg_img"])){
}
```

I use this on my scripts and works fine

Answer (score 0):

Return `false` when `$_FILES["beg_img"]` is empty, like:

```
if (empty($_FILES["beg_img"]))
{
    return false;
}
```